# Bind forwarding denied from externals

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I have two server with Bind installed. One is a public dns for resolving domains I own.
The other one should be another dns that I'd like to use for my customers.

On the first one i set the forwarding to the second one and I have created a forward zone for a domain, pointing to the second bind server.

Server1:

```
acl internals {
    172.16.0.0/24;
    127.0.0.1;
    };
acl domain {
    192.168.1.0/24;
    };
acl externals {
    any;
    };
```

```
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation yes;
#dnssec-lookaside auto;

version "Not your job";
recursion yes;
    
 allow-transfer { internals; domain;};
   // restrict query access
 allow-query { internals; externals; domain; };
   // restrict recursion
 allow-recursion { internals; domain; };

auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
forwarders {
    172.16.0.150;
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
    };
```

```
view "externals" {
    match-clients { "externals"; };
    recursion no;

    zone "my_customer_domain.com" {
    type forward;
    forwarders {
        172.16.0.150;
        };
    };
};
```

Server2 has the same configuration but should resolve only the my_*customer_*domain.com with an internal answer of 172.16.0.34 if the request is from "internals", the public IP if from "externals" and 192.168.1.4 if from "domain".

If I made a DIG from my pc (same subnet as "internals") i have the right answer (es: 172.16.0.34)
If I made a DIG from a domain pc (same subnet as "domain") i have the right answer (es: 192.168.1.4)
If I made a DIG from an external pc (dig NS my_*customer_*domain.com @8.8.8.8 ) I see in the Server1 logs:

**172.253.8.133**#43235 (my_*customer_domain.com): view externals: query failed (REFUSED) for my_customer_domain.com*/IN/NS at query.c:5425

All other kinds of queryes don't give any problem, even if I try to reach google.com from server2

Just tried allowing recursion for "any" on both servers and disabling dnssec params.

Note: server1 in "domain" and "internals" has "root zone". Server2 has "root zone" only for "internals"

Server1: ubuntu 20.04.05, Bind 9.16
Server2: ubuntu 20.04.05, Bind 9.16

Comment: Server configuration is not programming. You would be better asking this at [sf].

Comment: maybe you're right :-)
Thanks